# Using where query if data is not null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this query

```
$something = Something::where('height, '>=', $request->heightMin)
->where('height, '<=', $request->heightMax)
->get();
```

It works but what if I want to use field age. This filed isn't require so I may have value (int) or null. So if i had value "null", I want this field to be ignored. How can I do that?

Comment: Have a look at [when](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Does "isn't required" mean that there might be rows in the database where this value is not set, or that the value is optional in your request?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `when` to only apply the query when the value exists in the request.

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses):

> Sometimes you may want clauses to apply to a query only when something
> else is true. For instance you may only want to apply a `where`
> statement if a given input value is present on the incoming request.
> You may accomplish this using the `when` method:

```
$role = $request->input('role');

$users = DB::table('users')
                ->when($role, function ($query, $role) {
                    return $query->where('role_id', $role);
                })
                ->get();
```

> The `when` method only executes the given Closure when the first
> parameter is true. If the first parameter is `false`, the Closure will
> not be executed.

Something like this:

```
$something = Something::where('height', '>=', $request->heightMin)
    ->where('height', '<=', $request->heightMax)
    ->when($request->age, function ($query, $age) {
        // your query here
        $query->where('age', $age);
    })
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "Between":

MySQL Raw Query WHERE Statement Example:

```
WHERE height BETWEEN :heightMin AND :heightMax
```

Looks like laravel, if it is take a look at:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses

```
$something = Something::whereBetween('height', [1, 100])
->get();
```

However, if its not laravel, go in your IDE .. if you type just "where" if you find something like whereBetween in your autocompletion

If there is a problem with null values in the database you can do a (and)Where height IS NOT NULL .. You can also split your query like

```
$something = Something::where('height, '>=', $request->heightMin); 
if($request->heightMax !== null){
something = something->where('height, '<=', $request->heightMax)
}
something->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove `age` field and order you have to add where to your query like this:

```
$something = Something::where('height, '>=', $request->heightMin)
->where('height, '<=', $request->heightMax)
->where('age, '!=', null)
->get();
```

but if you want to have empty `age` field at the end of your query result and order just others that have value you should better do something like this:

```
$something = Something::where('height, '>=', $request->heightMin)
->where('height, '<=', $request->heightMax)
->orderBy(Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::raw('ISNULL(`age`), `age`'), 'ASC')
->get();
```